# Is the proof approach for $\sqrt[n]{\Pi_{j=1}^n x_j} \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ futile?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I need to prove for $n \in \mathbb{N} \text{\\} \{ 0\}$ and $x_j \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ that the inequality for geometric and arithmetic mean holds.

I use induction.

First, Let n=1, then it is clear that $x_1^{1/1} \leq x_1$

Therefore, step 2, assume the inequality holds for some $k=n$.

Step 3, I need to show that inequality holds $k+1$ from the fact that it holds for $k$. Therefore I write

$$\sqrt[k]{\Pi_{j=1}^k x_j} \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k x_j$$

It is clear that $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^kx_j < \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}x_j$, thus

$$\sqrt[k]{\Pi_{j=1}^k x_j} \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} x_j$$

It is also clear that $(x_1)^{(1/(k+1))}(x_2)^{(1/(k+1))}...(x_k)^{(1/(k+1))} < (x_1)^{(1/k)}(x_2)^{(1/k)}...(x_k)^{(1/k)}$, thus

$$\sqrt[k+1]{\Pi_{j=1}^k x_j} \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} x_j$$

I do not know exactly how to proceed now, I had the following idea, which incredibly dirty and probably won't lead anywhere. Define the difference between the RHS of the inequality above with the one where we divide each term by $1/k+1$ as the following:

$$\Delta^* = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}x_j}{k(k+1)}$$

The difference between the LHS of the same inequality and the one where we multiply by additional term $x_{k+1}$ is more dirty:

$$\Delta_*=\Pi_{j=1}^{k+1}x_j^{1/(k+1)}-\Pi_{j=1}^{k}x_j^{1/(k+1)}=\Pi_{j=1}^kx_j^{1/(k+1)}(x_{k+1}^{1/(k+1)}-1)$$

And so in theory if I prove that:

$$\Pi_{j=1}^kx_j^{1/(k+1)}(x_{k+1}^{1/(k+1)}-1) \leq \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}x_j}{k(k+1)}$$

then I have proceed it by induction. But it feels as if I have made matters worse. I would be interested to see if I can proceed with this approach any furhter?

Comment: Note for $n=1$ it isn't $\sqrt{x_1}$ but instead "first root" of $x_1$ on the left side. [Good thing it is...]

Comment: Very good indeed... thanks

Comment: should this the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: yes, this is GM-AM inequality

Comment: Note that if you are to prove this inequality then every inequality you use in the process has to be an equality for the case $x_1=x_2=\ldots = x_n$. Otherwise it's impossible to get the desired result. Your "It is also clear that" does not have this property.

Comment: why should every inequality have $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$?

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{\prod_{j=1}^n x_j} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ when all $x_j$ are equal. If you at any step use an inequality which is not exact for this special case then you cannot get an inequality that is.

Comment: thanks. That means my "proof" is rubbish. I have learned something very useful

Comment: If you look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), scroll down to the Cauchy induction method, which (IMHO) is neater than standard induction in this case.

Comment: beautiful, it has a couple of problems that I have been working on recently there as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let
$A_n
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k
$
and
$G_n
=\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k}
$.

Write
$A_{n+1}$
and
$G_{n+1}$
in terms of
$x_{n+1},
A_{n}$,
and
$G_{n}$.

Use the induction hypothesis that
$G_n
\le A_n$
and see what that gets you.

It might make it easier
if you assume that
$x_{n+1}$
is extreme
(i.e., either
$x_{n+1} \le x_k$
or
$x_{n+1} \ge x_k$
for
$1 \le k \le n$).

Comment: worked. I did not have to assume anything about the size of the $x_{n+1}$